# format routing symfony2 format

Tags: php, symfony

I have the routing this:

```
nueva_ventau:
   pattern:  /ventau/{id}
   defaults: { _controller: miomioBundle:Usuario:ventau, _format: pdf}
   options:
        expose: true
```

How could the redirect response with a format?

```
if ($pieces[0] == 0)//html
    return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('homepage')); ??????????????
else
return $this->forward('miomioBundle:Venta:hello', array('id' => $venta->getId()));
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with "redirect response with a format"?

Answer (score 2):

From [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/routing.html), being in a controller:

```
return $this->redirect(
    $this->generateUrl('nueva_ventau', array('id' => $venta->getId())
);
```